# Find $P(W_{t} < a | W_{2t} > a)$

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, conditional-probability

Here are my thoughts:
$P (W_{t} < a | W_{2t} > a) = \frac{P(W_{2t} > 2a, W_{t} < a)}{P(W_{2t} > 2a)} = 
\frac{P(W_{2t} - W_{t} > a,\, W_{t} < a)}{P(W_{2t} > 2a)}$

Then, taking into account the independency of increments of a Wiener process, this equals to:
$$
\frac{P(W_{2t} - W_{t} > a) * P(W_{t} < a)}{P(W_{2t} > 2a)}
$$
And then, all the components of this expression are known.
I was wondering if I made some mistakes in the steps above. Or my solution is legit?

Comment: The event $\{W_{2t}>2a, W_t<a\}$ is not the same as $\{W_{2t}-W_t > a, W_t<a\}$. For example, what if $a=1$, $W_t = -100$ and $W_{2t}-W_t=2$?  Then the latter event holds, but not the former. Another approach: You can condition on all possible values of $W_t$.

Comment: Could you expand on your answer please? I mean, do you suggest to split the probability into the parts where $W_{t} > 0$ and $W_{t} < 0$?

Comment: There are uncountably infinitely many possible values of $W_t$ and I was suggesting that you condition on all of them.  You seem to be conditioning only on two events $\{W_t>0\}$ and $\{W_t<0\}$ and you will never solve the problem that way.

Comment: But $W_{t}$ is an almost definetly continuous process. It means that it has continuum values.

Comment: You are saying the same thing as the first sentence in my comment.  I do not know why you started your sentence with "But..."

Comment: My question is this: How can i condition on all$ W_{t}$ values if their number is not countable?

Comment: If $A$ is an event and $X$ a continuous random variable with PDF $f_X(x)$ then the law of total probability in integral form is $$P[A] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P[A|X=x]f_X(x)dx$$